# Can I delete all materials of all objects in a scene quickly?

Tags: materials

Is there a quick way to delete all materials in the scene? I have a scene containing 20+ materials and all linked to objects. I'd like to remove all the materials from my blender file.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes, you can. Easy way would be:

1. Select all objects, keep one active, remove all materials on it by pressing the "-" button on the right-hand side of material slot list;
2. Then, from the drop-down list (below it), choose **Copy Material to Others**. Save the file.

[image]

All unused material data will be removed after saving. You cannot see them anymore after reopening.

Comment: I never knew such a thing ever existed. Found the button, done and gone.

Comment: This answer just saved me Two thousand, nine hundred and sixty five mouseclicks. You sir, are a legend.

Comment: @JachymMichal Glad to help sir. It's 2.8 now, and we still have to do this kinda quick and dirty trick... T_T

Comment: I have no materials assigned, and reopening the file doesn't remove any of them

Answer (score 25):

There's an addon *Material Utils*, which ships with Blender.

Enable it in the *User Preferences > Addons*, select all objects <kbd>A</kbd>, hit <kbd>Q</kbd> over 3D View and chose *Remove Material Slots*:

[image: Material Utils Addon - Remove Material Slots]

It currently works on the active object only, despite the tooltip stating it would work for multiple objects. Here's a scripted solution for all selected, editable (non-linked) objects:

```
import bpy

for ob in bpy.context.selected_editable_objects:
    ob.active_material_index = 0
    for i in range(len(ob.material_slots)):
        bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove({'object': ob})
```

Comment: According to the tooltip: "Remove all material slots from active objects", so a Copy Material to Others operation is still needed. Btw, you are supposed to suggest a coding way, I bet. :P

Comment: Interesting, it says **objects**, but seems to work on the active object only. I should either fix the tooltip or add an option to chose what to delete (slots of active object, selected objects, scene objects, all).

Comment: Yeah, This is the CoDEmanX I know of. XD

Comment: Added a scripted solution to really remove all slots of all selected objects :)

Comment: I'm working on the Material Utils addon and it looks like it currently fails for a lot of scenarios? I wonder how slot cleanup should behave, I could let it remove all empty slots (but they can actually be assigned without material!), or only slots with materials not used by the object, or a mix of both... Won't work for text objects however, they don't seem to expose the materials :(

Comment: this should be the right answer. I have over 100 materials in a generated object, using current best answer will be a nightmare...

Answer (score 25):

to delete all materials:

```
import bpy
for material in bpy.data.materials:
    material.user_clear()
    bpy.data.materials.remove(material)
```

Comment: You don't need `;` in python tho

Comment: Would it be an easy update to make your script remove the material slots too?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an updated version of [reflog's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24248/141070). This removes all materials programatically.

```py
for material in bpy.data.materials:
        bpy.data.materials.remove(material, do_unlink=True)
```

I was getting errors when using `material.user_clear()`, and read that it's something that shouldn't be done anymore. The above works flawlessly in the current version of Blender (3.0.0 at the time of writing).

Answer (score 0):

just had to solve this problem too. The other answers here didnt work for me.
My solution:

1. Select all of the objects you want to remove materials from.
2. In **Object Mode**, Join them (menu: Object/Join or shortcut: ctrl + 'j').
3. Remove the material(s) in the materials panel by pressing the '-' button.
4. In **Edit Mode**, select all ('a'), press 'p' and separate (by loose parts in my case) to get your individual objects back.

Comment: I'd use this if and only if none  of the original objects had loose parts,  or shared the same origin, or had meaningful names (mesh or object).

Comment: This might not work as expected for mesh objects containing several meshes, like e.g. monkey. After your procedure there will be monkey and 2 eyes objects. Answers shown here still work for this situation

Comment: above critiques accepted :o)