# Blender freezes when adding a material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I have recently installed the Pbr shader. I have created a material for a landscape mesh. Later I created a rock. I tried to add a material to the rock but the screen freezes. Blender doesn't work, and the mouse doesn't move.

Now every time I open up Blender and try to add materials to anything the same thing happens, the screen freezes. I'm using cycles.

Comment: Using all caps is considered rude. What do you mean by "*recently installed the PBR shader*"?

Comment: sorry, I didnt wanted to sound rude. With pbr shader I reffer to an aditional shader that´s free. I download it from http://remingtongraphics.net/?s=pbr

Comment: Blender 2.79a now has a built-in PBR shader called Principled shader. Try using that instead.

Comment: this problem dosnt allow me to open up the section of materials, I dont think I can change the shader. :/ Anyway, thanks ! :D

Comment: When opening the file try do it via Ctrl+O and unchecking Load UI option in the settings on the left, this will revert to startup file settings when opening. You can temporarily create another startup where Node Editor isn't present.. Then once opened remove all materials from the file, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7160/can-i-delete-all-materials-of-all-objects-in-a-scene-quickly. From your description seems that you saved PBR materials you downloaded into startup file as well

Comment: Mr Zak and Mike Pan solutions actually worked, Thanks :))))) Is there anyway I can thank your help? I mean, are there stars or something? Thanks for helping :)))