# Is there an easy way to remove unused material slots in an object?

Tags: modeling, materials

I have recently been importing and modifying models from sites such as CGTrader. When I work on the materials for models, it often seems that objects have unused material slots.

At the moment, I'm just going into Edit mode, clicking the "Select" button for each slot, then scouring the object to see if any faces are selected, before deleting the slot if it is unused.

However, it seems there should be a more efficient way of doing this. Can anyone enlighten me please?

Comment: For a python way you may want to consider [BSE How to remove all unused material slots from all objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208388/how-to-remove-all-unused-material-slots-from-all-objects)

Comment: On the right of the material list, there's a dropdown menu > Remove Unused Slots

Comment: Isn't python a bit overkill for this simple task? Just hit _A_ in the viewport to select all objects and use the _Clean Up_ > _Remove Unused Material Slots_ function like the answer suggests.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the 3D Viewport, in Object Mode, with the object selected, pick *Object > Clean Up > Remove Unused Material Slots*.

This also works with multiple or all objects selected.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Brinkmann - that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: I just added the last sentence for completion, @scurest gave the answer ;)

Comment: Well thank you both ;-)