# How to remove unused material slots in all objects if the objects are not selected?

Tags: python, materials, scripting, objects, scene

Please tell me.
How to remove unused materials in all objects if the objects are not selected?

I tried this code but didn't get what I wanted. This code does not remove unused materials in unselected objects.

[How to remove all unused material slots from all objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208388/how-to-remove-all-unused-material-slots-from-all-objects)

Correction. All unused slots in all objects

Comment: It's rather a problem of setting the object as active, not selected. Does this work ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/210499/86891

Comment: This also only works on selected objects. I would like at best to
 unused material slots have been removed from all bpy.data.objects

Comment: A variation of this answer then ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/129155/86891

Comment: This script also removes unused material slots for selected objects only.
Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Hehe you're right. I've added an answer to the other Q&A. See if it helps you https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/292562/86891

Comment: Yeees. Hooray
It worked, thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, Rusian, welcome! .. it looks as though you have a fix, thanks to @Gorgious, so the linked archive now qualifies as a genuine duplicate, and this post can be closed. If for any reason you disagree, edit to point out the distinction, and we can re-open.

Answer (score 0):

[Gorgious](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/86891/gorgious)
Helped me find the answer.
Here is the answer to my question

[Delete all materials that aren't assigned to a face?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129082/delete-all-materials-that-arent-assigned-to-a-face/292562#292562)