# Convert Blend file to GLTF with baked materials

Tags: blend-files, gltf

I am trying to convert MMD files into gltf files for use on the web. I use a plugin called https://github.com/powroupi/blender_mmd_tools to import them into blender, but when I export them, they don't keep their textures. I understand that this happens because the generated materials use complex nodes, so I was wondering if there was a quick way to flatten all materials into a simple unlit material.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHsix.jpg)

Comment: How about just removing all materials: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7161 ?

Comment: Can you edit this question to include a screenshot of the shader nodes output by that tool?

Comment: The preferred material setup is documented in https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html. You can use a process like https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake to bake a diffuse texture (or other things) which are compatible with that setup.

Comment: Thanks Don McCurdy I used the second process, I wasn't able to get it to work, but I did it again and it worked. :)

Comment: Can someone mark this as duplicate or make the comment an answer?

Comment: OK, I've made the comment an answer.

Comment: Thanks! I marked it as the answer already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred material setup is described in the Blender [glTF addon docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html). You can use a process like [How do I bake a texture using Cycles bake](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake) to bake a diffuse texture (or other things) which are compatible with that setup.